# Insert data in class without method c++

Tags: c++

I'm writing a C++ program where I read data from a file and insert it into a data class. My question is if it's a good idea to insert data into the class without using a method?

e.g.

```
mystream >> myclass.myvariable;
```

or it's better to use a method instead?

```
mystream >> my_temp_value;
myclass.insert(my_temp_value);
```

Comment: Use methods if you want to employ data abstraction and hiding principles of oop

Comment: How about myclass.load(istream mystream);  Puts the inserting code inside the class, where it belongs.

Comment: @MartinJames That might be fine if streams were copyable _and_ it made any sense whatsoever to make use of that property.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - oops, I derped into Java/Delphi mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class should have both data and behavior and used for abstraction. From theoretical perspective all data members should be private/protected. If you don't need any abstraction and behavior, then plain `struct` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest overloading the `>>` operator, because this hides the implementation of the class. If you just want to use the members directly, there's no reason to use a class, and you might as well use a `struct` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to wrap the class members and access them only through methods, plus it can make your program easier to understand for a reader.